# Painting the edges of an $n$-gonal prism with 3 colors all the edges of each vertex have different colors if $n= 2018$ and $n= 2019$?

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to paint the edges of a n-gonal prism with 3 colors so that each face has all 3 colors and all the edges of each vertex have different colors if a)n= 2018; b)n= 2019?

We can look at it as n=odd and n= even cases.

If n=odd:
Let us say one of the parallel faces has colour C1, then the three adjacent quadrilateral can be either C2 or C3. And this is not possible without repeating the colour. Hence, n=2019 is not possible.

If n=even:
Then let one of the parallel faces be C1, the 4 quadrilaterals can be coloured with C2 and C3 and the opposite face with C1. Hence, n=2018 is possible.

Now, this explanation doesn't take the colour of the edges in account. If we take them into account, how would we proceed then?

Comment: The title talks about coloring edges while the body talks of coloring faces.  Which is it?

Comment: The question goes like this: Is it possible to paint the edges of a n-gonal prism with 3 colors so that each face has all 3 colors and all the edges of each vertex have different colors if a)n= 2018; b)n= 2019? As far as I've understood, it is about the vertices having different colours.

Comment: "Let us say one of the parallel faces has colour C1." Why? Why say anything at all about the color of a face? Suppose you take one of the quadrilateral faces, paint two opposite edges of that face C1, then paint another edge C2 and paint the last edge C3. **None** of those colors is the color of the face; it does not have a color. That's how you "take the colour of the edges in account."

Comment: The question in your comment is much clearer than anything else.  Please edit it into the body of the question as comments sometimes disappear.

Comment: @DavidK So when it says in the question "each face has all three colours" is it talking about the colour of the face or does it mean that the edges of each face should have all three colours? Does this mean that the 'face' in itself has no colour and is irrelevant?
And also, does it mean that each vertex should be adjacent to edges of all three colours i.e. we cannot have a vertex which is adjacent to two C1 and one C2? Should every edge have adjacent C1,C2 and C3 edge?

Comment: I've tried to do it by drawing for n=3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. If we take our condition to be such that each face should have all 3 different coloured edges i.e. we cannot have a face where two edges are C1 and rest two are C2, then it works for n=2,3,6,8,9,10. So can we say that for multiples of 2 and 3, its true? Have I taken the right assumption?

Comment: The words "each face has all three colors" are not as clear as I would like, but yes, my interpretation is that each face must have at least one edge of color C1, one edge of color C2 and one edge of color C3, and the other edges may be colored any way you like.

Answer (score 1):

When the bases have an even number of sides, paint all the edges connecting the two bases with C1.  You can then paint alternating sides C2 and C3 to get a coloring that satisfies your requirement.  You cannot do this when the bases have an odd number of sides.

When the bases have a number of sides that is a multiple of $3$, paint one base with a cycle of C1, C2, C3.  Each edge then has the third color for its vertex and you can paint the other base with the cycle again.

Comment: This one I get it exactly but I don't get the one with the vertices. 
If we check for n=3, we successfully obtain a 3-prism satisfying the conditions.
If we check for n=4, then also we can successfully obtain a 4-prism with the given conditions. 
With n=5, I couldn't obtain a 5-prism with the given conditions.  
With n=6, I could obtain a 6-prism with the given conditions. 
So can we say that the conditions are satisfied for multiples of 2 and 3?

Comment: @Siddhartha Did you find for 4-prism the conditions?

Comment: @MathLasker Yes, it has to be done by induction. It was not very difficult. You just have to draw out the four prism in 2-dimensional form. For example, a 3-prism will be drawn as 3 adjacent squares. The left edge of the first square and the right edge of the third sphere is the same edge in our actual 3-prism. Similarly, a 4-prism can be drawn as 4 adjacent squares. After that, start colouring the edges. You will eventually get a condition for odd and even n.

Comment: @Siddhartha I get what a n-prims graph looks like, what I don't get is how to accomplish the condition of all the faces having all the three edge colors, In the case of the 4-prism there is always one face that missed one edge color; It is possible for you to show how do you do the edge coloring for the 4-prism?

Comment: What I think is that the only way for that particular edge coloring could happen is if there is a complete cycle of three colors in the graph, that means it only can happen if n is multiple of 3 so we can cycle the edge colors of the two n-polygon like c1,c2,c3,c1,..,c3 and then fill the edges than connects the polygon with a des phase cycle of the colors.

Comment: @MathLasker Yes, I just tried with n=4 and three colours, it is not possible to do so. This is my edge colouring diagram. https://ibb.co/C9xbMZK

Comment: @Siddhartha Exactly so the condition being even isn't good, I think the only way is what I explained in my previous comment but I need to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I remember now, after a point, I had to stop looking at odd/even and this multiple condition worked. You’re right.